# Can't get Array Interscet to work?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Trying to compare these two arrays, so the date list from $arr is cleaned and only shows the dates displayed on $schedule_1. but it's outputting array () and I can't figure out why!

```
// GENERATE DATE AND TIME ARRAY

// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// Start date
$date = date('Y-m-d H:') . "00";
// End date
$end_date = date ("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("+1 week", strtotime($date)));

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $arr[] = "$date";
    $date = date ("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("+30 minutes", strtotime($date)));
}


// #1 SCHEDULE
$schedule_1 = array(
"2017-11-14 12:00:00",
"2017-11-14 13:00:00"
);


print_r(array_intersect($arr, $schedule_1));
```

Comment: Your `$arr` array contains dates of the format `Y-m-d H:i`, but your `$schedule_1` array contains dates of the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. You didn't even `var_dump($arr, $schedule_1);` to see what you were trying to compare, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
$schedule_1 = array(
   'date1' => "2017-11-14 12:00",
   'date2' => "2017-11-14 13:00"
);
```

Alternatively, below code would solve your problem too:

```
$end_date = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 week", strtotime($date)));

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
  $arr[] = "$date";
  $date = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 minutes", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Comment: Or `$date = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s" ...`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Well, that would work to but OP just formatted without `second`, thats why I showed this way. I will update it as an alternative solution